# Where can I find garage building plans?

Tags: garage, construction, planning, workshop

If I wanted to build a detached garage/workshop, where can I find complete, detailed plans?  I'd like to be able to estimate building cost from a materials list.

I'm not certain what style I'd want, so I'm open to suggestions.  For sake of discussion, let's assume the main house structure is colonial or similar.

Comment: Do you mind paying for the plans, or do you want them for free?

Comment: Free would be nice, but I'm personally willing to reward an architect/supplier for having a good design.

Comment: Locking because if asked today this would fall under the product recommendation policy.

Answer (score 2):

In order of increasing cost:

This [website](http://www.cad-design-and-drafting-services.com/free-garage-plans.html) has a few good plans for simple garages available at no cost.

[TodaysPlans](http://www.todaysplans.com/directory-free-garage-plans.html) looks like it has some good plans for free, but you have to get them through email.

[Mybackyardplans](http://www.mybackyardplans.com/garageplans.php) has a few for free, but they look to be low quality.

This [website](http://www.cadnw.com/garage_l.asp) has them starting around $70.

[JustGaragePlans](http://justgarageplans.com/) has a wide range to pick from, but they're going to run $100+ per plan.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few free ones I found through a Google search.

[Build a Single Garage Shell](http://www.buildeazy.com/garage_1.html).

[Plan for a 16' X 22' Garage](http://www.rona.ca/rona/img/1750-1_ATTACHMENT1251121019633.pdf).

[20' X 24' Garage](http://www.sdscad.com/pdf/garagedemo.pdf).

There seems to be a lot of sites that will supply you with plans for a fee.  You may also be able to find blueprints of garages built in your city at the city clerks office, at least for garages built with permits (I think these are public record but I'm not sure).

You could also try using software like [Google Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/) or other drawing software to create your own plans, if you go this route make sure to get your plans approved by the appropriate government offices.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for garage plans, I could give you a few tips from my own experience. Therefore, you should make sure the plans come with detailed instructions and they comply with the local building codes. Make sure the garage plans talks about the foundation of the construction, as this will make a difference on the long run.

Personally, I have used [these](http://www.howtospecialist.com/garage/how-to-build-a-detached-garage/) plans, but I'm pretty sure there are more options to choose from. Otherwise, you could use instructions and just adjust the size and the design of the garage to your needs.

Comment: This answer is a little bit on the "chatty" side.  Try to tone it down in that aspect and just offer answers to the questions. "I've used XXX plans and they (didn't) work(ed) well for me..."